# RapidMiner on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management

I have fairly standard Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to use RapidMiner. There are neither official packages for RapidMiner nor unofficial PPAs.

When I [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rapidminer/files/1.%20RapidMiner/5.2/rapidminer-5.2.008.zip/download) it from the official website and ran `java -jar lib/rapidminer.jar` I get the following log:

```
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:34 AM com.rapidminer.tools.ParameterService init
INFO: Reading configuration resource com/rapidminer/resources/rapidminerrc.
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:34 AM com.rapidminer.tools.I18N <clinit>
INFO: Set locale to en.
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:35 AM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Property rapidminer.home is not set. Guessing.
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:35 AM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Trying parent directory of '/home/izidor/projects/rapidminer/lib/rapidminer.jar'...gotcha!
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:38 AM com.rapidminer.parameter.ParameterTypePassword decryptPassword
WARNING: Password in XML file looks like unencrypted plain text.
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:40 AM com.rapidminer.tools.jdbc.JDBCProperties <init>
WARNING: Missing database driver class name for ODBC Bridge (e.g. Access)
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:40 AM com.rapidminer.tools.jdbc.JDBCProperties registerDrivers
INFO: JDBC driver ca.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver not found. Probably the driver is not installed.
Oct 10, 2012 9:10:40 AM com.rapidminer.tools.jdbc.JDBCProperties registerDrivers
INFO: JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found. Probably the driver is not installed.
```

And the splash screen freezes at the stage `Loading icons` while using 100% of CPU.

How to make RapidMiner to run on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, I solved the problem just after posting the question :/ RapidMiner pops up a dialog window which the user has to confirm before she can continue. However, the dialog window is shown on another desktop :/

Solution is to check other desktops because there might be a dialog, like on the following screenshot:

[image: Situation]